# Border not appearing around MaterialCardView

Tags: android, xml, androidx, android-cardview

I'm trying to add a border around my `MaterialCardView` control but for some reason this is not working. I've already added the relevant dependency but it still doesn't seem to have any effect.

**Dependency added**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    ...
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:strokeColor="@android:color/black"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp">
[...]

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**Current result**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/item_img_card"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
  
    >
```

Comment: Still not working. Removing that line of code has had no effect at all.

Comment: @MacaronLover can you check my edited answer and try it

Comment: Why do I have to use a theme? My app has a dark theme too. That didn't work either.

Comment: u can ignore theme part, just try the latest version,
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'